# CS50 Finance - Sell (iterate over dropdown menu)

Tags: loops, jinja2, dropdown, cs50, finance

I am implementing a dropdown menu on a web page. In my controller code I'm grabbing data from a sqlite database and storing it in a variable called "portfolio". I'm then iterating over it on my html page with Jinja. I followed this same process with success on another page. The only difference is that that info was displayed in a table rather than a dropdown menu. I suspect something about storing items in the "option value" tags is causing me a problem.

Anyone able to help point in the right direction? Thanks.

[My problem: no stocks displaying in dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC7tK.png)

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
"""Sell shares of stock"""

# If a form is submitted
if request.method == "POST":
    symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
    shares_to_sell = int(request.form.get("shares"))

    # Access user's stock info
    portfolio = db.execute("SELECT symbol, SUM(shares) AS shares FROM purchases WHERE users_id = ? GROUP BY symbol", session["user_id"])
    for stock in portfolio:
        folio_symbol = stock["symbol"]
        shares_owned = int(stock["shares"])

        # Ensure stock is selected
        if not symbol:
            return apology("Must select a stock to sell", 403)

        # Ensure user owns that stock
        if symbol != folio_symbol:
            return apology("Can only sell stocks you own", 403)

        # If no shares selected
        if shares_to_sell < 1:
            return apology("Must select a number of shares to sell", 403)

        # If user does not own enough shares
        if shares_owned < shares_to_sell:
            return apology("User does not own enough shares to sell", 403)

        # Subtract shares sold from purchases table
        db.execute("UPDATE purchases SET shares = ? WHERE users_id = ?", shares_owned-shares_to_sell, session["user_id"])

        # Adjust cash in users table
        users = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", session["user_id"])
        cash = users[0]["cash"]

        stock_info = lookup(symbol)
        sell_amt = shares_to_sell*stock_info["price"]

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = ? WHERE id = ?", cash+sell_amt, session["user_id"])

        flash("Sold!")
        return redirect("/", portfolio=portfolio, stock=stock)

else:
    return render_template("sell.html")
```

HTML page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Sell Stocks
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h2>Sell Stocks</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Offload your shares below.</p>
    <br>
    <form action="/sell" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="symbol">
                <option disabled selected value>Stock</option>
                {% for stock in portfolio %}
                    <option value="{{ stock.folio_symbol }}">{{ stock.folio_symbol }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I forgot to grab my database info under my GET condition. Thus, the dropdown wasn't populating because there was no data available under that condition to populate it.